# Flutter show dialog box if no "Internet Connection"

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm beginner to Flutter development and im creating a webview app to load my responsive website into the app.
Everything works perfect but i need to show a dialog box saying "No internet connection" if there is no internet connection.

My code :

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool isLoading = true;
  ConnectivityResult? _connectivityResult;
  late StreamSubscription _connectivitySubscription;
  bool? _isConnectionSuccessful;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();

    _connectivitySubscription = Connectivity()
        .onConnectivityChanged
        .listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
      print('Current connectivity status: $result');
      setState(() {
        _connectivityResult = result;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    super.dispose();

    _connectivitySubscription.cancel();
  }

  Future<void> _checkConnectivityState() async {
    final ConnectivityResult result = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();
    if (result == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
      print('Connected to a Wi-Fi network');
    } else if (result == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
      print('Connected to a mobile network');
    } else {
      print(result);
    }

    setState(() {
      _connectivityResult = result;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        WebView(
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          // initialUrl: '',
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController controller) async {
            await WebviewCookieManager().setCookies([
              Cookie('SESSION-Test', 'token')
                ..domain = 'dobuyme.online'
                ..httpOnly = true
            ]);

            controller.loadUrl('https://example.com/source=web_view');
          },
          onPageFinished: (String url) {
            setState(() {
              isLoading = false;
            });
          },

          // onPageFinished: (finish) {
          //   setState(() {
          //     var isLoading = false;
          //   });
          // },
        ),
        isLoading
            ? const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )
            : Stack(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This variable will be "true" if connection is successful

```
_isConnectionSuccessful
```

But i don't know how to append this with the webview and check connection before website loads.
I want to show a message that says "No intenet connection" and close the app.

Please anyone can help. me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use [internet_connection_checker: ^0.0.1+4](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker) plugin to check if internet has available or not...

```
final StreamSubscription<InternetConnectionStatus> listener =
      InternetConnectionChecker().onStatusChange.listen(
    (InternetConnectionStatus status) {
      switch (status) {
        case InternetConnectionStatus.connected:
          // Do what you want to do
          break;
        case InternetConnectionStatus.disconnected:
          // Do what you want to do
          break;
      }
    },
  );
```

Here you you find the status....and show dailoge box when status is disconnected

Answer (score 1):

if you are a beginner use the default flutter internet poup package **package name:internet_popup**

`void initState() { super.initState(); InternetPopup().initialize(context: context); }`

add this line in init in your app.The package link[Click here to refer and use the package](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_popup/changelog)